# Sumproduct with two lists not in same order

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two lists that aren't in the same order but each list has a unique Identifier.

Table 1:

```
ID Commission Sales Group

100   $5       10     1 
200   $7       10     1 
300   $4       10     1 
400   $7       10     1 
500   $8       10     2 
600   $5       10     2 
700   $2       10     2
```

Table 2:

```
ID Commission Sales Group

100   $2       12     1 
300   $2       14     1 
400   $2       15     1 
600   $2       16     2 
500   $2       17     2 
700   $2       12     2
```

In this case I would need to Do the sumproduct of (Table 2 Sales) * (Table 1 Commission) when the group equals 1 (or 2 depending). The issue I am having is that the order isn't always the same on both tables and IDs drop out (but are never added back). Is there a way to a sumproduct between the two? I have hundreds of these tables and I need to multiply the Table i Sales by the Table i-1 Commission. I am also unable to sort the data as it would take a long time (not to mention things won't line up due to missing ID numbers). Any help would be appreciated. I am looking at historical data so I need to do this calculation a 100 times and show it all on a summary table along with other information.

The tables would be on sheets labeled 1,2,3 etc (was going to make my own indirect). and yes, it would only multiply the numbers where the IDS are the same. I would want to take the commission rate from table 1 (the end of the previous month) and multiply it by the sales of table 2 (the sales of the current month). I would want to sum up all the commissions for group 1 and group 2. For group 1 I would need to do ($5 * 12) for ID 100 +($4 * 14) for ID 300 + ($7*15) for ID 400 giving the group 1 total commission (ID 100,300,400) to be $221. I would then need to do the same thing for group 2.

Comment: You want this to multiply only when the ID is the same?  Also, where are the tables located?

Comment: Hi. Can you just explain how you arrive at the results in the example you give above?

Comment: I made some errors copying it over. I updated the main post with the correct information.

Comment: Why are the IDs out of order in the second table?  Is that a strict limit of the problem, or can tables be sorted by ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory you can get the result for group 1, assuming Sales from table2, multiplied by commission from table1 for each relevant ID with the following formula

> =SUMPRODUCT((Group2=1)+0,SUMIF(ID1,ID2,Commission1),Sales2)

Assumes all IDs are shown in table1 once and once only

.....but in your example in the question the commission shown against each ID is the same in each table, so if that was always the case you'd only need the data from table 2

Your example in comments doesn't make any sense to me, you have $7*13, for example, but there's no 13 in either table so I don't know where that comes from

Comment: Yeah I fixed the error in the main post. I also changed the commissions in post two to be clearer. They aren't always the same numbers. I'll try out that formula thanks for the help and follow up once I get the chance

Comment: Looking at the edits you made then I think that formula should work for you - let me know if you get any problems

Comment: Hi Barry,

Worked like a charm. I only needed to change Sales2 to ID2! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yeah, I messed that up a bit, you still need Sales2 in there but ID2 should be in the SUMIF, apologies, I was typing it on the train! Edited now....

Comment: No worries. I ended up doing exactly what you put in your edit. It works beautifully!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the work for a [Pivot table](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Quick-start-Create-a-PivotTable-report-0c220f35-e478-49aa-beaf-24018b7f0f64)